# Leap motion + ubuntu + python

Tags: python

I installed the leap motion (Linux/Ubuntu) hot fix `.deb` file on my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

I am using python.

When I try to run a `hello_world.py` it fails to import the leap module.

The above deb file installed fine. And I can start the service.
I also can activate the GUI (leapmotioncontrol, I think that's the name). I can get the floating hands with my leap motion unit plugged into my box.

I've tried utilizing their hello_world code, but can't seem to locate the module.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these links:

- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openleap/PyLeapMouse/issues/16)
- [Stack Overflow question - No Module Named Leap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133578/importerror-no-module-named-leap)

Solution posted on GitHub issue:

> You need to download the SDK from this [link](https://developer.leapmotion.com/sdk/v2). In this you can find
>   a folder named LeapSDK. Copy it to your `$HOME` (`/home/user` where
>   `user` is your username) and do this:
>
> ```
> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/LeapSDK/lib:$HOME/LeapSDK/lib/x64
> ```